# Format a constexpr const char*

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm working with __ PRETTY_FUNCTION __, C++11, that is formated like: (type Class::Object(parameters), but I need to format my string like (Class::Object()).

I know how to remove "type" from my string with constexpr. I can simply return a pointer skipping space, like this:

```
inline constexpr const char* removeType(const char* expression) noexcept
{
    return (*expression == ' ') ? expression+1 : removeType(expression+1);
}
```

This is working very well! But I can't think of a way to remove "parameters" from my string. I thought I could find "(" in my original expression and put a ") \ 0" after that. But I can't change this string because it's a constant, and that would also change the __ PRETTY_FUNCTION __ return behavior.
So, what can I do to create a new string (char* or const char*) in a constexpr and format it removing something in the middle of it?

Comment: You are trying to replace part of the string from being `(args...)` to being `()`. Since this is a mutating operation, and this is in a `constexpr` context in C++11, the only way you will be able to accomplish this is with constructing a _new_ string containing the name of the function name by building it in a variadic pack expansion (e.g. as an array of characters) -- which won't be easy. Why exactly do you need this functionality?

Comment: In my company we log some information from our methods, including when it starts and finishs. All logs are formated as (Class::Method() - message).
For start and finish, I've created an object where the constructor will print "begin" and destructor "end". To make everything simpler, I'm using PRETTY_FUNCTION and some macros so I don't need to pass classname and methodname on every call.
I would like to have this format because some other messages have this format.

Comment: Separately, types can have spaces, e.g. `const char*` or even `std::map<int, const char*>`, so `removeType` as shown is unreliable.

Comment: The macros are working, but I have this parameters printed

Comment: @TonyDelroy you are actually right... So it's worse than I thought

Comment: Well, perhaps you can search for a `(`, then back up to the previous space, and return a `std::string_view` to that range, adding an extra `)` in the logging code.

Comment: I will try, thank you :)

Comment: Actually, that won't work reliably either - functions that return lambdas will have `(` in their return type.  But, can work around such cases if you're patient and careful.

Comment: wouldn't `__FUNCTION__` do the trick if you didn't want the return type or parameters?

Comment: If the whole purpose of this is for logging, why not extract the class name and the function name independently, and log them? E.g. parse out the class name from `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, and then use `__func__`? No mutation necessary in this approach. In printf-style logging this would effectively just become `"%.*s::%s()"`

Comment: Use __FUNCTION__ would do the trick to format method, but I still don't know how to extract class name (there is no __CLASS__).
Of course, I can easily do everything on runtime, but I would like to do it in compile time for processing efficiency. How can I extract class name and store it on compile time?

Comment: Appending with method name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a crack, ignoring the obvious caveat that `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is a propriety GNU convention that can't be counted on for any guarantees in the formatting. My strategy was to start at the last ')', and then do a search for '(' while balancing parenthesis to avoid tricky parameters like function pointers. But then I was able to make this:

```cpp
struct baz {
    template <typename T>
    decltype(auto) complex(int y, foo<int(*)()> a) const noexcept {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return 42;
    }
};
baz{}.complex<decltype(&biff)>(42, foo<decltype(&bar)>{});
```

Which produced:

```
decltype(auto) baz::complex(int, foo<int (*)()>) const [with T = float (*)()]
```

So, I made a helper function to do a search, balancing `[]`, `<>`, `{}`, and `()`, *just in case*.

```cpp
constexpr const char* balancedReverseSeek(bool(*predicate)(char), const char* begin, const char* current) {
    size_t squareLevel = 0;
    size_t carrotLevel = 0;
    size_t parenLevel = 0;
    size_t braceLevel = 0;
    
    const char* c = current;
    for (; c != begin && (!predicate(*c) || squareLevel || carrotLevel || parenLevel || braceLevel); --c) {
        switch (*c) {
            case ')':
                parenLevel++;
                break;
            case '(':
                parenLevel--;
                break;
            case ']':
                squareLevel++;
                break;
            case '[':
                squareLevel--;
                break;
            case '>':
                carrotLevel++;
                break;
            case '<':
                carrotLevel--;
                break;
            case '}':
                braceLevel++;
                break;
            case '{':
                braceLevel--;
                break;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Then this seems to work ok, and it gets the class name (`baz::complex`):

```cpp
constexpr std::string_view getName(std::string_view prettyName) {
    if (prettyName.empty()) {
        return prettyName;
    }

    const char* signatureEnd = prettyName.data() + (prettyName.size() - 1);
    const char* paramEnd = balancedReverseSeek([](char c) { return c == ')'; }, prettyName.data(), signatureEnd);
    if (paramEnd != prettyName.data()) {
        paramEnd--;
    }
    const char* nameEnd = balancedReverseSeek([](char c) { return c == '('; }, prettyName.data(), paramEnd);
    if (nameEnd != prettyName.data()) {
        nameEnd--;
    }

    const char* nameBegin = balancedReverseSeek([](char c) { return c == ' '; }, prettyName.data(), nameEnd);
    return { nameBegin, nameEnd - nameBegin + 1 };
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/W578vP